# Emulating lambdas in C?

Tags: c, lambda, code-generation

I should mention that I'm generating code in C, as opposed to doing this manually. I say this because it doesn't matter too much if there's a lot of code behind it, because the compiler should manage it all. Anyway, how would I go around emulating a lambda in C? I was thinking I could just generate a function with some random name somewhere in the source code and then call that? I'm not too sure. I haven't really tried anything just yet, since I wanted to get the idea down before I implement it.

Is there some kind of preprocessor directive I can do, or some macro that will make this cleaner to do? I've been inspired by Jon Blow to try out compiler development, and he seemed to implement Lambdas in his language Jai. However, I think he does something where he generates bytecode, and then into C? I'm not sure.

Edit:
I'm working on a compiler, the compiler is just a project of mine to keep me busy, plus I wanted to learn more about compilers. I primarily use clang, I'm on Ubuntu 14.10. I don't have any garbage collection, but I wanted to try my hand at some kind of smart pointer-y/rust/ARC inspired memory model for garbage collection, i.e. little to no overhead. I chose C because I wanted to dabble in it more. My project is free software, just a hobby project.

Comment: In what context are you generating C code? With which operating system and compiler? Why C and not something better (Common Lisp or Ocaml)? Are you implementing some compiler? Do you have a garbage collector? Please edit your question to improve it.

Comment: What is the project, what is its URL?

Comment: Too bad your language don't have GC or closures.

Comment: Aye, I mean it's a possibility. I'm just kinda goofing around with ideas at the moment, also you got any books on code generation to another source language that you can recommend?

Comment: I strongly recommend Queinnec's Lisp In Small Pieces (and it is worthwhile to learn a bit of Scheme, perhaps simply to understand that book)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it ("having" lambdas in C). The important thing to understand is that lambdas give [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) and that closures are mixing "code" with "data" (the closed values); notice that objects are also mixing "code" with "data" and there is a similarity between objects and closures. See also [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/263094/40065) on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Traditionally, in C, you not only use function pointers, but you adopt a *convention* regarding [callbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29). This for instance is the case with [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/): every time you pass a function pointer, you also pass some data with it. You can view callbacks (the *convention* of giving C function pointer with some `void*`data) as a way to implement closures.

Since you generate C code (which is a wise idea, I'm doing similar things in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) which -on Linux- generates C++ code at runtime, compile it into a shared object, and `dlopen`-s that) you could adopt a callback convention and pass some closed values to every function that you generate.

You might also consider closed values as `static` variables, but this approach is generally unwise.

There have been in the past some `lambda.h` header library which generates a machine-specific [trampoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computing%29) code for closures (essentially generating a code which pushes some closed values as arguments then call some routine). You might use some [JIT compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques (using [libjit](http://savannah.gnu.org/git/?group=libjit), GNU [lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), ....) to do the same. See also [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) to call an *arbitrary* function (of signature known at *runtime* only).

Notice that there is a strong -but indirect- relation between closures and [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (read the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) for more), and it is not by accident that every [functional language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) has a GC. C++11 lambda functions are an exception on this (and it is difficult to understand all the intricacies of memory management of C++11 closures). So if you are generating C code, you could and probably should use [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) (which is wrapping `dlopen`) and you would have closure GC-ed values. (You could use some other GC libraries, e.g. [Ravenbrook's MPS](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps) or my unmaintained [Qish](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/qishintro.html)...) Then you could have the convention that every generated C function takes its closure as first argument.

I would suggest to read [Scott's book on *Programming Language Pragmatics*](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) and (assuming you know a tiny bit of Scheme or Lisp; if you don't you should learn a bit of [Scheme](http://www.schemers.org/) and read [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)) [Queinnec's book *Lisp In Small Pieces*](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) (if you happen to read French, read the latest French [variant](http://paracamplus.com/spip/?page=livre&isbn=978-2-916466-03-3)).

Comment: @user3839220: However, please edit your question to improve it. I'm very curious about what you are doing, why you are asking, and how do you generate C code? Is your project free software?