# Is it possible to "typedef"(of sorts) a function prototype?

Tags: c, typedef, function-prototypes

I have multiple functions that are similar to each other - they take in the same arguments, and return the same type:

```
double mathFunction_1(const double *values, const size_t array_length);
```

I already use typedef'd pointers to those functions, as I store them as an array to easily use any number of them on the same data, map them etc.:

```
typedef double (* MathFunction_ptr )(const double *, const size_t);

double proxy(MathFunction_ptr mathfun_ptr, const double *values, const size_t array_length);
```

What I want to achieve, is a similar ease-of-use with declaring and defining the functions, as I already have with using pointers to them.

---

Thus, I was thinking about using a similar typedef to make it easier for me to write the actual functions. I tried doing it like this:

```
// declaration
typedef double MathFunction (const double *values, const size_t array_length);
MathFunction mathFunction_2;
```

The following approach works partially. It lets me "save a few keystrokes" in the declaration, however the definition has to be fully typed out.

```
double mathFunction_2(const double *values, const size_t array_length)
{
    // ...
}
```

---

What I found by searching more for this issue is this: [Can a function prototype typedef be used in function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574985/can-a-function-prototype-typedef-be-used-in-function-definitions)

However it doesn't provide many alternatives, and only reaffirms that what I tried to do in my other experiments is forbidden according to the Standard. The only alternative it provides is using

```
#define FUNCTION(name) double name(const double* values, size_t array_length)
```

which sounds clunky to me(as I'm wary and skeptical of using the preprocessor).

What are the alternatives to what I'm trying to do?

---

Two other approaches I tried that don't work(and, as I just read, are forbidden and absolutely wrong according to the C standard 6.9.1):

1.This approach doesn't work, as it means that I'm telling it to define a variable mathFunction_2(I believe that variable is treated as a pointer, though I don't understand this well enough yet) like a function:

```
MathFunction mathFunction_2
{
    // ...
}
```

2.This approach doesn't work, as it means I'm telling it to create a function which returns a function(unacceptable in the C language):

```
MathFunction mathFunction_2()
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It simply *can't* be used in a definition. But at least you get the compiler to check your functions match the expected prototype before you convert to a pointer. That's neat, isn't it?

Comment: The macro solution is the way to go. If you are afraid of the preprocessor, you are either poisoned by C++ or need anxiety therapy :-)

Comment: @Jens Not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Jens: It's both actually(my first language was C++), plus I want everything I can to be kept as the C code, and only use preprocessor for things that can't be done in code(like #include and guarding headers).

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't exactly understand what you are trying to say. Do you mean how I define a "double function(args)" after declaring it as "MathFunction function"? Though that leaves the problem of the "MathFunction_pointer" being defined separately from "MathFunction".

Comment: I mean that the approach that lets you "save a few keystrokes" is actually a fair bit more then you give it credit for.

Comment: Please confirm if I'm understanding it correctly. Do you mean, that my approach of "saving a few keystrokes" has the benefit of checking the types of the function pointers?

Comment: Did you look into [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/)? You might find it interesting!

Comment: As OP is interested in "save a few keystrokes". note that the [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions) 2nd `const` in `double mathFunction_1(const double *values,  /* here */ const size_t array_length);` serve no functional purpose.  Same effect as `double mathFunction_1(const double *values,  size_t array_length);`

Comment: @tehftw - I mean that it both expresses intent/usage and allows the compiler to check it for correctness. Imagine a better type name. Imagine you are declaring a `UIActionFunction my_cb;`. It says what that function will be. It conveys more than just a bunch of parameters and a return type. The compiler will check the definition against it (as it would for any prototype). But if you need to change what a `UIActionFunction` is, then all the places in the code will be highlighted immediately upon rebuild, for any function declared by that type alias. It's already doing quite a lot.

Comment: If only this were C++, then you can use lambdas...

Comment: Indeed, if only it wasn't my own exercise with a goal to learn about programming in the C language... Don't worry fellow human, I'm generally more of a C++ background, and learn both of those amazing languages.

Answer (score 8):

You could use a `typedef`  for the signature (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9143434/841108)):

```
typedef double MathFunction_ty (const double *, const size_t);
```

and then *declare* several functions of the same signature:

```
MathFunction_ty func1, func2;
```

or declare some function *pointer* using that:

```
MathFunction_ty* funptr;
```

etc... All this in [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)), read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

> however the definition has to be fully typed out.

Of course, since you need to give a *name* to each formal parameter (and such names are *not* part of the type of the function) in the function's *definition*. Therefore

```
double func1(const double*p, const size_t s) {
  return (double)s * p[0];
}
```

and

```
double func1(cont double*arr, const size_t ix) {
   return arr[ix];
}
```

have the *same* type (the one denoted by `MathFunction_ty` above), even if their formal parameters (or formal arguments) are named differently.

You might abuse of the preprocessor and have an ugly macro to shorten the *definition* of such functions:

```
// ugly code:
#define DEFINE_MATH_FUNCTION(Fname,Arg1,Arg2) \
   double Fname (const double Arg1, const size_t Arg2)
DEFINE_MATH_FUNCTION(func1,p,s) { return (double)s * p[0]; }
```

I find such code confusing and unreadable. I don't recommend coding like that, even if it is certainly possible. But sometimes I do code something similiar (for *other* reasons).

<sup>(BTW, imagine if C *required* every first formal argument to be named `$1`, every second formal argument to be named `$2`, etc...; IMHO that would make a much less readable programming langage; so formal parameter's name matters to the human reader, even if systematic names would make the compiler's life simpler)</sup>

Read also about  [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), [anonymous functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) (C don't have them but C++ has [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)), [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) (they are *not* C functions, because they have closed values so mix code with data; C++ has [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)-s), [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) (a necessary *convention* to "mimick" closures)... Read [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), it will improve your thinking about C or C++. Look also into [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29427906/841108) answer.

Comment: UV for [covering all the bases](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cover+all+the+bases).

Comment: Massive props and thanks to you Brasile Starynkevitch - I learned a bit Scheme is an amazing language, especially GNU Guile and Racket inmplementations. Overall, your answer is way more than I expected, which is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately in C I don't believe there is any way to do what you're asking without using preprocessor macros, and personally at least I agree with your assessment that they are clunky and to be avoided (though this is a matter of opinion and open to debate).

In C++ you could potentially take advantage of [`auto` parameters in lambdas](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generic-lambdas).

The example function signatures you show here really aren't complicated and I wouldn't worry about the perceived duplication. If the signatures were much more complicated, I would view this as a "code smell" that your design could be improved, and I'd focus my efforts there rather than on syntactic methods to shorten the declaration. That just isn't the case here.

Comment: If I understand correctly - the way I did it is the preferred(correct?) way of doing things? And as long as I don't have a big list of function arguments, it should be fine?

Comment: @tehftw Yes, what you are doing is just fine in my book. Using a `typedef` for pointers to functions that match a certain signature is common and accepted in C. And there is no problem with having many functions with the same signature, even if it is annoying that you have to type them all out!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  Indeed, that's the purpose of the `typedef` declaration, to use a type identifier to declare a type of variable.  The only thing is that when you use such a declaration in a header file:

```
 typedef int (*callback_ptr)(int, double, char *);
```

and then you declare something like:

```
 callback_ptr function_to_callback;
```

it's not clear that you are declaring a function pointer and the number and type of the parameters, but despite of this, everything is correct.

Finally, I want to note you something particularly special.   When you deal with something like this, it is normally far cheaper and quick to go to the compiler and try some example.  If the compiler does what you want without any complaint, the most probable thing is that you are correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef double (*ptr_to_mathematical_function)(double);

extern double find_zero(ptr_to_mathematical_function f, double aprox_a, double aprox_b, double epsilon);

int main()
{
#define P(exp) printf(#exp " ==> %lg\n", exp)

    P(find_zero(cos, 1.4, 1.6, 0.000001));
    P(find_zero(sin, 3.0, 3.2, 0.000001));
    P(find_zero(log, 0.9, 1.5, 0.000001));
}

double find_zero(
    ptr_to_mathematical_function f, 
    double a, double b, double eps)
{
    double f_a = f(a), f_b = f(b);
    double x = a, f_x = f_a;

    do {
        x = (a*f_b - b*f_a) / (f_b - f_a);
        f_x = f(x);

        if (fabs(x - a) < fabs(x - b)) {
           b = x; f_b = f_x;
        } else {
            a = x; f_a = f_x;
        }
    } while(fabs(a-b) >= eps);
    return x;
}
```

The second, and main part of your question, if you are having such a problem, the only way you can solve it is via using macros (see how I repeated the above `printf(3)` function calls with similar, but not identical parameter lists, and how the problem is solved below):

```
#define MY_EXPECTED_PROTOTYPE(name) double name(double x)
```

and then, in the definitions, just use:

```
MY_EXPECTED_PROTOTYPE(my_sin) {
    return sin(x);
}

MY_EXPECTED_PROTOTYPE(my_cos) {
    return cos(x);
}

MY_EXPECTED_PROTOTYPE(my_tan) {
    return tan(x);
}
...
```

that will expand to:

```
double my_sin(double x) {
...
double my_cos(double x) {
...
double my_tan(double x) {
...
```

you can even use it in the header file, like:

```
MY_EXPECTED_PROTOTYPE(my_sin);
MY_EXPECTED_PROTOTYPE(my_cos);
MY_EXPECTED_PROTOTYPE(my_tan);
```

As it has been pointed in other answers, there are other languages (C++) that give support for this and much more, but I think this is out of scope here.